# Updating label in other class with a function

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to display a message that is send from another class. I'm using a function to do this. But the problem is that the message doesn't display when I change the ViewController.

Setting the message:

```
StartViewController().showMessage(message: "Test Message", color: UIColor.green)
```

Displaying the message:

```
func showMessage(message: String, color: UIColor){

    messageLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Verdana")
    messageLabel.text = message
    messageLabel.fontSize = 15
    messageLabel.fontColor = color
    messageLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)

    self.addChild(messageLabel)
}
```

(These are 2 different file and ViewControllers)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `StartViewController()` is initializing a new `StartViewController` and then calling the method. You need to reference your current `StartViewController`.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for answering! May I ask you how I can do that? I can't find a tutorial on Google about this.

Comment: @stefffeyens Hi steff, you can find a useful project in XCode 8 - File - New - Project (tab application) and select Game. Here you have a SpriteKit demo with a 'Hello world' label. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here there is a little confusion between **UIKit** and **SpriteKit**.

A `ViewController` has no member `addChild`, I think you would speak about `SKNode` object.

In **SpriteKit** , if you want to display a `SKNode` element or an objects that inherit `SKNode`, first of all you should cast your view as a `SKView` then instantiate and present a `SKScene` as explained for example in the *"Hello world"* project :

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
}
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("This is my GameScene, here I could show my SKLabelNode")
    } 
}
```

Also, in **SpriteKit** you don't need to change viewController to display your elements, you can present a new `SKScene` or show directly a `SKNode`

---

To help you about your function you can do also:

```
func showMessage(message: String, color: UIColor,pos:CGPoint)->SKLabelNode{
        let messageLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Verdana")
        messageLabel.text = message
        messageLabel.fontSize = 15
        messageLabel.fontColor = color
        return messageLabel
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let messagePos = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
let messageLabel = showMessage(message:"Test Message", color: UIColor.green, pos:messagePos)
self.addChild(messageLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your new vc in a property and push/present it

```
self.startVC = StartViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.startVC, animated: true)
```

When you want to display the message just call the `showMessage()` func

```
self.startVC.showMessage()
```